# Can we use multiple if statements with one else statement?

Tags: c

After running the program i am getting output for my else statement when my if statement is true!

I wrote a program to find whether the given input was positive, negative and even, odd respectively

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
        printf("positve and even");
    }

    if (n > 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
        printf("posiitvetive and odd");
    }

    if (n < 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
        printf("negative and odd");
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        printf("invalid");
    } else {
        printf("negative and even");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code for readability.  Those `if` statements should be at the same level (column).

Comment: Make sure you accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written the last `if` is what the `else` operates on so your program will print "negative and even" if `n != 0`.  This is probably not what you want here.

You can use a chain of `if() {} else if() {} ... else {}` so the `else` only block applies if none of the `if` or `else if` conditions were true.

For this problem I suggest you nest your `if` statements to avoid repeating the conditions:

```
if(n > 0) {
   printf("positive and ");
   if(n % 2 == 0) printf("even");
   else printf("odd");
} else if(n == 0) {
   // ...
} else { // n < 0
   printf("negaitve and ");
   if(n % 2 == 0) printf("even");
   else printf("odd");
}
```

The 3 print statements in the `if` and `else` block look very similar so we would like to reduce the duplication.  You may notice that the output is in one of two forms:

- `n!=0` aka `n`: ("positive" or "negative") "and" "even" or "odd")
- `n==0` aka `!n`: "invalid

Which you could implement like this:

```
if(n)
   printf("%s and %s",
      n < 0 ? "negative" : "positive",
      n % 2 ? "odd" : "even"
   );
else
   printf("invalid");
```

Comment: Pick up a good textbook like "The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition" but you need to find a way to supplement with changed since C90 particular initialization in C99 perhaps https://en.cppreference.com/w/c ?  It's all about using what you learn to solve problems.

Comment: No, sorry, this is not something I can help you with.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgs-gOIId40&t=38s :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to bind them together with `else`s and don't forget to check that `scanf` succeeds.

- `scanf` returns the number of successful extractions from the stream (the number of assigned variables) or `EOF` if there was an error before any variable could be assigned. Since you have one conversion specifier (`%d`) in your `scanf` format string, `scanf` should return `1` if it was successful. If it does *not* return `1` OR if it returns `1` and `n` was assigned the value `0`, print `invalid`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter the number");

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0) {
        puts("invalid");
    } else if (n > 0 && n % 2 == 0) {
        puts("positve and even");
    } else if (n > 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
        puts("posiitvetive and odd");
    } else if (n < 0 && n % 2 != 0) {
        puts("negative and odd");
    } else {
        puts("negative and even");
    }
}
```

Or you could make it sligtly less verbose:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char* np[] = {"negative", "positive"};
    const char* oe[] = {"odd", "even"};

    int n;
    printf("enter the number");

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0) {
        puts("invalid");
    } else {
        printf("%s and %s\n", np[n > 0], oe[n % 2 == 0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping me solve my problem. sir i need help with the code you provided.  the following line i didn't understood         if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0) {
        puts("invalid")                                                                                                               how you put scanf statement in if (condition )??        and sir i really need help in c programming from the basic can you teach me!! please sir

Comment: `scanf()` returns how many elements was read, so that expression says if you didn't read 1 element or the value read was 0 then print invalid.  Another way of writing it would be `int rc = scanf("%d", &n); if(rc != 1 || n == n) { ...`. Always check return values otherwise you will be wasting time debugging.

Comment: bro i didn't got what your are telling me !! please explain me with an example please bro??                                                                                      and also the else statement  how it calculating 2 condition in same line like 'np' hows its printing n and p separately??

Comment: @ShahSuraj I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @ShahSuraj _"how it calculating 2 condition in same line like 'np' hows its printing n and p separately??"_ - A boolean expression like `n > 0` becomes `0` if `false` and `1` if `true`, so `np[n > 0]` becomes either `np[0]` or `np[1]` depending on if `n > 0` or not.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  thank you sir !   sir can you teach me c programming ??  or if its not possible can you suggest me some good websites and books to study c from?

Comment: @ShahSuraj Perhaps one of these books will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list - See if you can find one that covers C17

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo can you help me write a program to find sparse of a matirx and transpose of it.                                                                                                                                                       and sir c program to convert infix to postfix  using stack and  switch case condition

Comment: @ShahSuraj I'm afraid you've misunderstood what Stackoverflow is about. It's about asking and answering specific programming related questions - and those are the reasons I visit here. If you have a specific question, just write a new question about that and someone may have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Skirting the `scanf()` worries, you can achieve your objective with a single call to `printf()` that uses the conditional operator 3 times. The most of the code below is running 5 different tests, and prepending output of the value and appending a LF to each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void allYouNeed( int n ) {
    printf(
        !n ? "invalid" : "%stive and %s",
        n < 0 ? "nega" : "posi",
        n % 2 ? "odd" : "even"
    );
}

void show( int n ) {
    printf( "%2d ", n );
    allYouNeed( n );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) {
    show( -2 );
    show( -1 );
    show(  0 );
    show(  1 );
    show(  2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
-2 negative and even
-1 negative and odd
 0 invalid
 1 positive and odd
 2 positive and even
```

**EDIT:**
A better version without using helper functions to isolate a proposed solution to the OP's problem...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    for( int i = -2; i <= 2; i++ ) {
        printf( "%2d ", n );

        /* All that is needed in one printf statement */
        printf( 
            !n ? "invalid" : "%stive and %s",
            n < 0 ? "nega" : "posi",
            n % 2 ? "odd" : "even"
        );

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcc -Wall` generates the "warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]" for the invalid case.

Comment: I might delete one of your files as punishment if I had to search for one of the keywords of the output and not finding it :-) If someone had internationalize code like this they would probably do worse.  Not really of course but figured you might appreciate the humor. Better name?  Good call on including test cases.

Comment: In a dynamic language allYouNeed would probably return a string so you can get those 2+1 printf+putchar statements down to 1. Is there a great way in C? Expose the innards of the allYouNeed as a macro so you can build the whole thing in show()? And yes, it's way off course for a beginner but I was curious on your take.

Comment: @AllanWind `allYouNeed()` was simply to isolate the `printf()` to match the OP's output. `show()` does the bracketing output around the OP's desired output. And `main()` should have been a `for()` loop (meaning no need for `show()`.) Dashed off too quickly?? Cheers! `:-)` (Saved 4 bytes of redundant text!! Whoopie!!! :-)  )

Comment: I understand why you did those two functions and eliminating `show()`.  Still curious if you had any thoughts on getting around the "redundant" printf+put statements in the current design.  It's another way of getting how to generate text templates, and the only low overhead thing I have seen is scatter writes.

Comment: @AllanWind I don't have much experience with this (that my aging brain recalls) but for a recent project dealing with HTML. When I twigged to using "prefix/postfix" functions, the hierarchical HTML output (open/close tags) was (imho) _a thing of beauty!_ `:-)`... That was actually quite a fun little project! Next??? JSON files??? `:-)`

Comment: Getting rusty in old age? :-)  I couldn't help it the pun.

Comment: @AllanWind re: `gcc -Wall` burps... Nice that the compiler can be so helpful... While I cop it for using an `int` for an array index variable (where `size_t` would be more appropriate), I sorta figure it's the coder who should be responsible, not the admirable gurus who write compilers... C triumphs because **is** the Wild West... Who wants to live the prescribed, dogmatic life of a monk in a monastery?? `:-)`

Comment: "rusty"??? I tell people I used to be an Iron-man... but was left out in the rain... `:-)`

Comment: You, sir, are funny.  Clearly, those people lack (fine) culture otherwise they would not be impresed as only pre-Mark III rust per https://www.britannica.com/question/What-is-Iron-Mans-suit-made-of.  Can't believe I actually looked that up AND that was the first result.

Comment: @AllanWind In my world, "iron man" refers to tri-athletes who subject themselves to grueling punishments (some mother's sons, eh?) The cherry on the top of my disappointment with "The Martian" came when Damon spoke the line "fly like Iron Man" in a movie said to be "scientifically accurate"... Sigh... Stop the world, please; I'd like to get off now... `:-)`