# can we write scanf statment in if condiiton in c programming?

Tags: c

i tried writing scanf statement in my if condition block , but everytime i am  getting the same output which was written in my if statement , even the condition fails!!! i getting the same output!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (){
    int m ;
    printf("enter the number");
    if( scanf("%d",&m)<=30){
       printf("c");}
    else if(m>=30&&m<70){
       printf("b");}
    else if(70<=m&&m<90){
       printf("a");}
    else if(90<=m&&m<=100){
       printf("a+"); }
     else{
       printf("fail");
                   }
}
```

```
 output
```

```
enter the number30
```

```
c
```

```
enter the number88
```

```
c
```

last time i send one question and someone send me answer with writing scanf statement in  if statement .

i am trying to give grade to the marks input by the user.

Comment: Absolutely you can write it. But it doesn't do what you want it to do, because the return value of `scanf` isn't the value (or values) read.

Comment: You can't use `scanf` like that. The return value is not the input value so it will not do what you expect. Do the ``scanf` first and then check the value. Like: `if( scanf("%d",&m) != 1) { // Input erro}; if( scanf(m)<=30) { ... }`

Comment: Look at the man page for `scanf`.  The return value is the number of items that it successfully read.  You should *always* check this.  Don't just assume that the user entered a valid value.

Comment: `else if(m>=30&&m<70){` This condition does not make much sense. The case `m==30` is already included in the condition before. You can't have it in the `if` nramch and in the `else` branch as well. Also, if the first part is not true, you would not come to that line at all because that is what the previous `if` is all about. You can simply use `else if (m<70) {` instead.

Comment: "last time ..." If you look closely at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77468104/can-we-use-multiple-if-statements-with-one-else-statement/77468149#77468149), the return value of `scanf` was checked and also value of `n` was checked in the first condition: `if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0)` You only do half of the job. And also be aware that all the following `else if` branches cannot check `scanf` any more. Therefore the first condition must do the error check and only the others can do the separate ranges.

Comment: (Absolutely you can write it. But it doesn't do what you want it to do, because the return value of scanf isn't the value (or values)read??)  why its like that ? bro i am not getting what are you saying ? actually i am a beginner in c programming. can you explain me in simple terms?

Comment: You need to read the documentation of `scanf`. The return value is not the same as the value you enter. Just think about using `scanf` to read 2 values. Which one should be the return value? For a successfull result it must return `1` in your code. This will always be `<=30`. It does not check what you have entered at all. That is stored in `m` which you do not check in first condition.

Comment: @Gerhardh bro can you help me with c programming???

Comment: Stackoverflow cannot replace some basic learning of the language. If the linked duplicate does not answer your question you need to revisit your beginners material